How to create a simple component inline?
I have a component that looks like this:
App.vue
<template>
  <RouterView />
</template>

I would like to not have a file for such a simple component. How would I go about creating such a component inline?
I tried the following and it works to some extend but the router-view is not being recognized as such:
defineComponent(() => () => h('router-view', {}))


h() should use real component like h(RouterView, it's not supposed to resolve it by its name. "I would like to not have a file for such a simple component." - it still makes sense for future use because all global logic automatically goes to App.vue

Regarding the comment above, I hence think that you need to find a way to import it from vue-router somehow. I don't think that you can straight use it like that but maybe.

@kissu Sure, it can be used like that. For some third-party ones resolveComponent('vue-router') could be used but here this is not needed

import { RouterView } from 'vue-router'!

defineComponent(() => () => h(RouterView, {}));

